# Cef browser not loading if not attached to a parent control

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I have a scenario where I'm creating dynamic instances of the Cef browser (i.e chromium) in a Windows Forms application.

I'm doing things in the following order :

- Creating the browser ;
- Navigating to a local HTML page ;
- Calling some JavaScript function to modify its content ;
- Appending the user control that contains the web browser to a parent control (which is a TabPage control) ;

It seems to me like the browser does not load, i.e IsBrowserInitializedChanged event is not fired, as long as the browser is not attached in the control tree of the displayed from.

Can anyone confirm this behaviour ? I did not find any information about this in the documentation of Cef browser. Thanks !

Comment: The browser is created when the `Handle` is created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you be more specific ?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2004/11/24/all-about-handles-in-windows-forms/